# What is the next process after i have stored the LinkedIn access token in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linkedin-api, access-token

it's been a long time since i have busted all my brains on this issue .

I know how to integrate LinkedIn to my native iPhone application. I also know a little bit about how OAuth works so , i downloaded OAuthStarterKit from https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

I did a little research and i was able to find out that the access token i being generated here  " - (id)initWithHTTPResponseBody:(const NSString *)body "

Now i can store that into keychain or i can actually store that in Database. I understand that part.
Now comes my question , what to do next ? i want the api call to use this access token , what should i code for that.

Methods in OATokenManager.m have code for saving but i can't seem to understand what is actually going on ?

All the documentation and threads at Linkedin Developer sites have code for Javascript or Ruby on Rails  but i need it for Xcode ( objective c) , i really need help here.

I am sorry i know my body is a little messy , but please suggest i will edit it accordingly, but please do not down vote.

Comment: Anybody who could help me out her e? please ?